# Fuzzy join without proc SQL

Tags: merge, sas, fuzzyjoin

Good day,

I wish to merge two dates to *next closest*.

Datasets are huge 500Mb to 1G so `proc sql` is out of the question.

I have two data sets. First (Fleet) has observations, second has date and which generation number to use for further processing. Like this:

```
data Fleet
    CreatedPortalDate 
    2013/2/19 
    2013/8/22 
    2013/8/25 
    2013/10/01 
    2013/10/07 

data gennum_list
    date 
    01/12/2014 
    08/12/2014 
    15/12/2014 
    22/12/2014 
    29/12/2014 
    ...
```

What I'd like to have is a link-table like this:

```
data link_table
    CreatedPortalDate date 
    14-12-03  01/12/2014 
    14-12-06  01/12/2014 
    14-12-09  08/12/2014 
    14-12-11  08/12/2014 
    14-12-14  08/12/2014
```

With logic that

`Date < CreatedPortalDate and (CreatedPortalDate - date) = min(CreatedPortalDate - date)`

What I came up with is a bit clunky and I'm looking for an efficient/better way to accomplish this.

```
data all_comb; 
  set devFleet(keep=createdportaldate);
  do i=1 to n;
    set gennum_list(keep=date) point=i nobs=n;
    if createdportaldate > date 
        and createdportaldate - 15 < date then do;/*Assumption, the generations are created weekly.*/
           distance= createdportaldate - date; 
          output; 
        end;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=all_comb; by createdportaldate distance; run;

data link_table; 
    set _all_comb(drop=distance); 
    by createdportaldate; 
    if first.createdportaldate; 
run;
```

- Any ideas how to improve or approach this issue?
- Ignorant idea: Could I create hash tables where `distance` would be stored.
- Arrays maybe? somehow.

EDIT:

- *common format*

  - Done
- *Where does the billion rows come from?*

  - Yes, there are other data involved but the date is the only linking variable.
- *Sorted?*

  - Yes, the data is sorted and can be sorted again.
- *Are gen num dates always seven days apart ?*

  - No. That's the tricky part. Otherwise I could use `week`and `year`(or other binning) as unique identifier.

Comment: Please edit so dates shown are all common format such as yyyy-mm-dd.  You only list unique date values in the sample data. 100 years has only ~36,500 days.  Where does the billion rows come from ? Are there other columns such as account id involved ?  The sample data shown is sorted.  Is the real data sorted ? Are gen num dates *always* seven days apart ?

Comment: @Richard updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Huge is a relative term, today's huge is tomorrow's speck.

Key data features indicate a direct addressing lookup scheme is possible

- Date values are integers.
- Date value ranges are limited.
- A date value, or any of the next 14 days will be used as a lookup verifier
- The key is a date value, which can be used as an array index.

Load the Gennum lookup once as follows

```
array gennum_of ( %sysfunc(today()) ) _temporary_;
if last_date then
  do index = last_date to date-1;
    gennum_of(index) = prev_date;
  end;

last_date = date;
```

And fetch a gennum as

```
if portaldate > last_date
  then portal_gennum = last_date;
  else portal_gennum = gennum_of ( portaldate );
```

If you have many rows due to grouping by account ids, you will have to clear and load up the gennum array per group.

Answer (score 1):

## This is a typical application of a sas `by` statement.

The `by` statement in a `data` step is meant to read two or more data sets at onece sorted by a common variable.

The common variable is the date, but it is named differently on both datasets. In `sql`, you solve that by requiring equality of the one variable to the other `Fleet.CreatedPortalDate = gennum_list.date`, but the `by` statement does not allow such construction, so we have to rename (at least) one of them while reading the datasets. That is waht we do in the `rename` clause within the options of `gennum_list`

```
data all_comb;
    merge gennum_list (in = in_gennum rename = (date = CreatedPortalDate))
          Fleet (in = in_fleet);
    by CreatedPortalDate;
```

I choose to combine the `by` statement with a `merge` statement, though a `set` would have done the job too, but then the order of both input datasets makes a difference.

Also note that I requested sas to create indicator variables `in_gennum` and `in_fleet` that indicate in which input dataset a value was present. It is handy to know that this type of variables id not written to the result data set.

However, we have to recover the `date` from the `CreatedPortalDate`, of course

```
    if in_gennum then date = CreatedPortalDate;
```

If you are new to sas, you will be surprised the above statement does not work **unless** you explicitly instruct sas to `retain` the value of date from one observation to the nest. (Observation is sas jargon for row.)

```
    retain date;
```

And here we write out one observation for each observation read from the `Fleet` dataset.

```
    if in_fleet then output;
run;
```

## The advantages of this approach are

- you need much less logic to correctly combine the observations from both input datasets (and that is what the `data` step is invented for)
- you never have to retain an array of values in memory, so you can not have overflow problems
- this sollution is of order 1 (O1), in the size of the datasets (apart from the sorting), so we know upfront that doubling the amount of data will only const double the time.

  ## Disclaimer: this answer is under construction.

It will be tested later this week

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. Looking forward to more. However, I'm not sure if this works when the two dates (`created` and `date`) are not matching. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are probably missing the function of the `retain` statement.